# How to set up Name Servers on my VPS?

Tags: ubuntu, vps, nameserver, domain-name

I am a complete newbie to server administration and I bought myself a cheap unmanaged VPS to learn to do something on my own and not be so tied to other people.

So far things have been going on great, I have nginx installed, configured with basic URL rewriting and SSH and repositories ready. OpenSSL is also working well.

However, I do not seem to understand how to set up Name Servers. Currently I'm accessing my site through the dedicated IP. As I understand it, I have to setup NS on my VPS and then put them on GoDaddy's preferences page.

I am using Ubuntu Server 11 x86-64. What packages I should be installing and what are the essentials to configure them? Any help, links, references are greatly welcome!

Edit: My hosting provider does not provide name servers.

Comment: Who are you hosting the unmanaged VPS's with? Usually I would use their own DNS and nameservers.

Comment: I'm hosting with http://www.sshvm.com/. So, I should look to them?

Comment: Yeah, I would. Ask them for their nameservers and that's what you enter into GoDaddy. There are ways of hosting your own DNS and nameservers but it's simpler to use theirs if you're planning on learning.

Comment: Are there some great hosting control panels (free) that I could install?

Comment: Webmin is free http://www.webmin.com/, there are many options though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend getting the nameservers from your hosting provider (sshvm.com) and then adding their NS records to GoDaddy.

Comment: It seems they don't provide name servers. What are my other choices?

Comment: You could use an external DNS provider to keep things simple? PointHQ as an example. They give you a nameserver to use with GoDaddy and you point the A records at your static/dedicated IP. https://pointhq.com/

Comment: you can use xname.org - it's free, and its great. Put their nameservers into godaddy and setup xname.org as needed.

Comment: I've registered an account with PointHQ. What type of records do I need to add? Is there a tutorial I could follow or something I don't understand these Aux Data, etc. are?

Comment: I'm not sure if they have tutorials or not but the main one to add to test it's working is an A record for www the resolves to your dedicated IP address. Once that's working then worry about the others. As an example in PointHQ click 'Add a record' choose A from the drop down menu, then enter www into the Name field. Then enter your IP address into the Data field and leave Aux. Data blank. Then visit your domain name with www. before and see if it works (allow time for DNS propagation).